# How to fire controller with JQuery and tokenInput

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-tokeninput

I am using TokenInput and MVC 3 C#.

I would like to get this bit of JQuery to work, but it never passes in the string to the method in my controller class from the input box.  What am I doing wrong.

**Create.cshtml**

```
<input type="text" id="authorlist" name="q" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("GetAuthors", "Author")" />
```

**AuthorController.cs**

```
public ActionResult GetAuthors(string term)
        {
            term = term.ToUpper();
            var authors = db.AUTHOR
                .Where(a => a.FULL_NAME.ToUpper().StartsWith(term))
                .Select(a => new { id = a.AUTHOR_ID, name = a.FULL_NAME});

            return Json(authors, "application/json", Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
  $("#authorlist").tokenInput('/author/getauthors/' + $(this).val(), {
        hintText: "Select Authors",
        searchingText: "Searching..."
    });
```

I would have preferred to the JQuery in a more MVC way by actually callling **data-autocomplete** value and triggering the ActionResult that way, but I was getting lost, as you can see:

```
$("#authorlist").tokenInput($(this).attr("data-autocomplete"), {
        hintText: "Choose authors"        
    });
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your url building, because TokenInput uses the query parameter `q` by default but in your action you are using `term`.

You have two oprions:

Change the action signature:

```
public ActionResult GetAuthors(string q)
{
}
```

Configure TokenInput:

```
$("#authorlist").tokenInput($(this).attr("data-autocomplete"), {
        queryParam: 'term',
        hintText: "Choose authors"        
    });
```

Comment: OMG - so simple and a hundred pieces of the jigsaw have fitted into place - thanks a million mate.